# Display image from sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, cross-site

Our intranet site aaa.com has a page with img src=bbb.com/image.jpg.
bbb.com is a sharepoint online site.

Chrome blocks the image display with this error:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html.<br>
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id...<br>
```

It appears sharepoint online is trying to authenticate.
This doesn't happen when the src is to an sharepoint on-premises site.

**How do i fix this?**

I've googled quite a bit, but can't tell if it's a configuration issue on aaa.com (our intranet site) or a configuration on bbb.com (sharpoint online site).
I tried adding `crossorigin=""` and `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the image tag - no luck.

It appears we should be able load "media resources":
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/site-isolation

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the picture to base64 format.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/displaying-the-users-profile-picture-in-your-office-365-add-in/

You still need to get SharePoint authorization.

Or you could try to login in SPO in the browser and the picture will appear.